# jQuery ajax gives an error even though it connected

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

This is probably something really small and stupid, but here's the issue: I am currently using AJAX in a sort of online file manager that I'm building. It uses AJAX to make a listing of files in a directory on the server, and that call works just fine. I'm now trying to add an AJAX call for file modifications (rename and delete). Using $.ajax, it successfully sends data to the server, which does what it is supposed to. It's successfully able to rename and delete files. However, the ajax method still executes the error code. Here's the call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "server.php",
    data: {
        action: action,
        filepath: filename,
        newname: entName
    },
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (jd) {
        if (jd.status === "error") {
            if (debug) console.log("AJAX connection error");
            window.alert("AJAX error. Please try again later.");
        } else {
            if (debug) console.log("AJAX connection success for modification.");
            if (debug) console.log("JSON data:");
            if (debug) console.log(jd);
            //changeContent(filename, action);
        }
    },
    error: function () {
        window.alert("Unable to connect. Please try again.");
        //This gets executed
    },
});
```

I figured it would be that the server didn't return any data, so I tried this code to test it:

```
if ($action == "load") { //It isn't in this case - I use this to load content
    $files = glob("media/" . "*");

    echo json_encode($files);

} else {
    $files = glob("media/" . "*");
    echo json_encode($files);
}
```

...and I'm still getting an error message. What could be wrong here?

Comment: Add `header('Content-Type: application/json')` to your PHP

Comment: inspect the request in browser console and see what status is and if any data is sent back that it is valid. If status is 500 you have a server code error, if returned data is not valid JSON will through a parseerror

Comment: Consider use a browser like Google Chrome, open up the console, and check whether HTTP/500 is returned. You can also check networking to see the actual content being returned, with header. From that you can start debugging your problem. Keep in mind that only a server error, HTTP404 401 500 will cause the error handler to be executed.

Comment: Adding the header function did not seem to work. Looking in the console does not appear to specify whether or not HTTP/500 was returned. How do I check that?